# R How to delete any string within []

Tags: r, gsub

I have a question about deleting any string within [].

My text data has a pattern that always start with [author name, date] or so.

For example, "[Report by Jeongho Choi: "Korea's Alarms Its Citizens"] [Text] Of all ~~"

The two text within [] is useless, so I want to delete [Report by Jeongho Choi: "Korea's Alarms Its Citizens"] and [Text].

Comment: You only want to keep `Of all ~~`?

Comment: Yes! Of all ~~ is the main paragraph that I am interested

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
srng <-  "[Report by Jeongho Choi: 'Koreas Alarms Its Citizens'] [Text] Of all ~~"

trimws(gsub("\\[[^][]*]", "", srng))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Of all ~~"
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter option would be the following. The used regular expression is `\\[` for opening brackets, `.` for any character `*` that appears zero or more times, followed by a closing brackets `\\]` and a space  .

```
a <- c("[Report by Jeongho Choi:'Korea's Alarms Its Citizens'] [Text] Of all ~")
gsub("\\[.*\\] ", "", a)
```

Output

```
"Of all ~"
```